# WPF DataGrid hold focus while refresh item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I use a DataGrid in WPF to display some values. The values refresh all 1000 milliseconds.

Now if I focus one row, and the event refresh the selected row, the focus is lost.

Are there any options to hold the focus active?

Here is my DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dgItems" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,10,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="White">
       <DataGrid.CellStyle>
              <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                     <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
              </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Name}">
                      <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                           <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                               <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 0 8 0" />
                           </Style>
                       </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wert" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Value}">
                      <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 0 8 0" />
                            </Style>
                       </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                 </DataGridTextColumn>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Zeit" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding DisplayTime}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                             <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 0 8 0" />
                             </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                   </DataGridTextColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

The Update function

```
private void UpdateItem(String ItemName)
{
    foreach(RecItem item in dgMain.Items)
    {
        if(item.Name == ItemName)
        {
             Modify item...
             ....
        }
    }

    dgMain.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that does the refresh? Are using `clear()` and `AddRange()`? If so this is may be the problem of the 'lost' focus

Comment: I wrote a  litte example function. I am not at work. But this snippet is exactly what I do ;-)

Comment: try to remove the refresh(), if DataGrid is bounded to an observable collection you may not need it.

Comment: I dont use a Observable Collection because (i dont know how to realize) I update the Items from a RefreshEventHandler in a other class than MainWindow.
So I can't pass the dgMain to the Event. Do you know how to solve this?